# Post deobfuscated Javascript code

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I used this tool http://code.google.com/p/cremebrulee/ to make obfuscated code more readable and the output is looking quite nonsensical

`function ____(_O0){eval(unescape(_O0))}
var l2=window.opera?1:0;function l3(l4){l5=/zc/g;l6=String.fromCharCode(0);l4=l4.replace(l5,l6);var l7=new Array(),l8=_1=l4.length,l9,lI,il=16256,_1=0,I=0,li='';do{l9=l4.charCodeAt(_1);lI=l4.charCodeAt(++_1);l7[I++]=lI+il-(l9<<7)}while(_1++<l8);var l1=new Array(),l0=new Array(),Il=128;do{l0[Il]=String.fromCharCode(Il)}while(--Il);Il=128;l1[0]=li=l0[l7[0]];ll=l7[0];_l=1;var l_=l7.length-1;while(_l<l_){switch(l7[_l]<Il?1:0){case 0 :l0[Il]=l0[ll]+String(l0[ll]).substr(0,1);l1[_l]=l0[Il];if(l2){li+=l0[Il]};break;default:l1[_l]=l0[l7[_l]];if(l2){li+=l0[l7[_l]]};l0[Il]=l0[ll]+String(l0[l7[_l]]).substr(0,1);break};Il++;ll=l7[_l];_l++};if(!l2){return(l1.join(''))}else{return li}};var lO='';for(ii=0;ii<OO0O.length;ii++){lO+=l3(OO0O[ii])};if(naa){document.write('<scr'+'ipt>'+lO+'</sc'+'ript>')};`

What might be the next step to do with this code?

update: this is the original code http://pastebin.com/qG4DX7qy

Comment: I guess it doesn't quite deobfuscate as well as you'd hoped...

Comment: Yeah, you should just go line by line, or try to find the obfuscated code wherever you found the obfuscated code.

Comment: Best you can do is this: http://pastebin.com/qZuewnUu and then try to go line by line and see what it does..

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: @ Lee Taylor - seems you're right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how it looks like after processing by the [jsbeautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/):

```
function ____(_O0) {
    eval(unescape(_O0))
}
var l2 = window.opera ? 1 : 0;

function l3(l4) {
    l5 = /zc/g;
    l6 = String.fromCharCode(0);
    l4 = l4.replace(l5, l6);
    var l7 = new Array(),
        l8 = _1 = l4.length,
        l9, lI, il = 16256,
        _1 = 0,
        I = 0,
        li = '';
    do {
        l9 = l4.charCodeAt(_1);
        lI = l4.charCodeAt(++_1);
        l7[I++] = lI + il - (l9 << 7)
    } while (_1++ < l8);
    var l1 = new Array(),
        l0 = new Array(),
        Il = 128;
    do {
        l0[Il] = String.fromCharCode(Il)
    } while (--Il);
    Il = 128;
    l1[0] = li = l0[l7[0]];
    ll = l7[0];
    _l = 1;
    var l_ = l7.length - 1;
    while (_l < l_) {
        switch (l7[_l] < Il ? 1 : 0) {
            case 0:
                l0[Il] = l0[ll] + String(l0[ll]).substr(0, 1);
                l1[_l] = l0[Il];
                if (l2) {
                    li += l0[Il]
                };
                break;
            default:
                l1[_l] = l0[l7[_l]];
                if (l2) {
                    li += l0[l7[_l]]
                };
                l0[Il] = l0[ll] + String(l0[l7[_l]]).substr(0, 1);
                break
        };
        Il++;
        ll = l7[_l];
        _l++
    };
    if (!l2) {
        return (l1.join(''))
    } else {
        return li
    }
};
var lO = '';
for (ii = 0; ii < OO0O.length; ii++) {
    lO += l3(OO0O[ii])
};
if (naa) {
    document.write('<scr' + 'ipt>' + lO + '</sc' + 'ript>')
};
```

The next step would be to go through every variable and function and give them better names (left as an exercise for the reader).

Of course this code is not complete - eg. some functions never get called, some arrays are never populated etc.

What this code does is put every element of the `OO0O` array through the `l3()` function (that decrypt the text that was encrypted using some naive home-brew encryption algorithm), joins them together and evaluates it all by putting `<script>`*result*`</script>` into the DOM using `document.write`. Since the `OO0O` array is not defined in the code you quoted we can't know anything what it does, because the actual (encrypted) code is in the `OO0O` array.

Actually you don't really need to know how the encryption algorithm works at all since all you need to do is step through this code with a debugger and examine the `l0` variable just before the call to `document.write` - and there you will have all of the actual code in a plain unencrypted form just before it is evaluated.

You can even put:

```
document.write = console.log;
```

just before that script is called and see all of the code printed to your console instead of being evaluated. I did it with the code that you posted in the pastebin in the update to your question and there is so many "undefined" strings in it that I think it's broken or incomplete or something went wrong with the charset encoding.

Where did you get it from, anyway?

Comment: `document.write('<scr' + 'ipt>'...)` Uh oh..I smell something funky going on with this code.

Comment: Don't worry, `OO0O` is undefined.

Comment: @Casper Actually the `document.write('<scr' + 'ipt>' + lO + '</sc' + 'ript>')` is equivalent to `eval(lO)` (but maybe run after other things in this script are called - here there are no other things). You have to break the `</script>` string in two parts because otherwise the HTML parser would think that your script ends here. I don't know why the first `<script>` is broken too - if the intent of putting `script` tags into the DOM was a secret then I think it would be hidden better - because now it is pretty much the only obvious thing in the original obfuscated code.

Answer (score 0):

You can prettify your code:

http://jsbeautifier.org/

But then you're on your own really. Any sense of legibility, variable/function names, etc. are lost forever. The only way around this is to get the original source.